# Variable devuelve valor antes de asignarselo Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que sirve para cerrar un trabajo pendiente, desde dicha función llamo a otra función que se llama `compruebaEan()`

```
let errEan = compruebaEan(primero);
console.log('completar ' + errEan);
if ('ko' === errEan) {
    erroresEan++;
} else {
    valorEan.innerHTML('input-incorrecto');
}
```

La función `compruebaEan()`es esta:

```
    /**
 * @param posicion
 */
function compruebaEan(posicion) {
    let url = '{{ path('almacenes_packing_list_cdn_comprubea_ean') }}';
    let formData = new FormData();
    let ean = $('#detalle_ean_'+posicion);

    formData.append('ean', ean.val());
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (output) {
            console.log('comprueba ' + output);
            if ('ko' === output) {
                ean.addClass('input-incorrecto');
                ret = 'ko';
            } else {
                ret = 'ok';
                ean.removeClass('input-incorrecto');
            }
        },
        error: function (salida) {
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Viendo ambos `console.log()` veo que devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el orden tendría que ser al revés

He actualizado la funcion de esta forma pero me sigue pasando lo mismo:

```
/**
 * @param posicion
 */
function compruebaEan(posicion) {
    let url = '{{ path('almacenes_packing_list_cdn_comprubea_ean') }}';
    let formData = new FormData();
    let ean = $('#detalle_ean_'+posicion);
    formData.append('ean', ean.val());
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (output) {
            if ('ko' === output) {
                ean.addClass('input-incorrecto');
                ret = 'ko';
            } else {
                ret = 'ok';
                ean.removeClass('input-incorrecto');
            }
        },
        error: function (salida) {
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    }).then((ret) => {
        return ret;
    });
}
```

Comment: Estás haciendo una llamada asíncrona con Ajax, probablemente el tiempo de respuesta sea el causante de que se ejecute el segundo log primero. Podrías usar la función .then() para que la parte del código que quieres que se ejecute después, se ejecute cuando obtengas respuesta.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de usar .then?

Comment: Puedes hacer que la respuesta se obtenga de manera síncrona añadiendo el par atributo-valor `async: false`, pero la alternativa del método `.then()` es más limpia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tienes una petición Ajax que se ejecuta de forma asíncrona, esto significa que en el momento en el que llegas la parte de Ajax, el código sigue ejecutándose, mientras que el fragmento de código referente a Ajax espera hasta obtener respuesta.

Esto habitualmente se soluciona usando la funcion `.then()`, que se ejecutará inmediatamente después de que tu llamada obtenga respuesta.

```
$.ajax({
  //Tu código

}).then((res) => {
  console.log('completar ' + errEan);
  if('ko' === errEan){
    erroresEan++;
  }else{
    valorEan.innerHTML('input-incorrecto');
  }
});
```

Comment: He editado el post con la funcion con un .then() pero me sigue pasando lo mismo, seguramente esté haciendo algo mal...

Comment: @PavloB. ¿Tienes el console.log dentro del ámbito del `.then()`? Por la forma en la que has editado el post, parece que no. Si quieres que algo se ejecute esperando a una respuesta por parte de ajax, tienes que colocarlo dentro del ámbito del then.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que, el console log sí que devuelve el resultado correcto primero, peor después de eso, veo que donde asigno el valor en función de la función me dice que es undefined... Es decir, el orden es correcto, pero al parecer por dentro no ....

Comment: @PavloB. ¿Te parece si nos movemos a una sala de chat y lo miramos?

Comment: Vale, no sé como se hace, pero.

Comment: Entra en este [enlace](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131377/sala-con-pavlob-y-aritzbn) y hablamos :)

Comment: probaste usar Promise.all con setTimeout(()

Comment: @PavloB. si te ha servido agradecería que marques la respuesta como correcta, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la promesa, que se usa principalmente, para operaciones asíncronas. De este modo, lo que haces es que hasta que no termine uno, no se ejecuta la otra función. Te paso el enlace. [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Te paso un ejemplo de cómo sería, teniendo tu código.

```js
function compruebaEan(posicion) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    let url = '{{ path('almacenes_packing_list_cdn_comprubea_ean') }}';
    let formData = new FormData();
    let ean = $('#detalle_ean_'+posicion);
    formData.append('ean', ean.val());
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (output) {
            console.log('comprueba ' + output);
            if ('ko' === output) {
                ean.addClass('input-incorrecto');
                ret = 'ko';
            } else {
                ret = 'ok';
                ean.removeClass('input-incorrecto');
            }
            
            resolve(ret);
        },
        error: function (salida) {
            reject(salida);
        }
    });
});
}


Promise.resolve(compruebaEan(primero)).then(function(result){
    console.log('completar ' + result);
    if ('ko' === result) {
        erroresEan++;
    } else {
        valorEan.innerHTML('input-incorrecto');
    }
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("error: " +error);
});
```